# Display timestamp onEdit in one cell but watch a whole table

Tags: google-apps-script

I am working with the script below on a GSheet:

```
function onEdit(e) {
var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet(),
    editCols = [2, 3, 4, 10, 11, 12]
if (sheet.getName() !== 'Dashboard' || editCols.indexOf(e.range.columnStart) ==
    -1 || e.range.rowStart < 3 || e.range.rowStart > 6) return;
sheet.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1).setValue(new Date())
```

}

The last line, I believe, will display the timestamp in column 1 on the row that was edited in a table of data (Rows 3-6 and columns 2, 3, 4, 10, 11, and 12).

What I would like, however, is for the timestamp to *only* be displayed in one cell in column 1 (e.g. cell A6).

How do I modify the setValue(new Date()) line to accomplish this?

Thanks for looking!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify the [Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range) for the `getRange()` function in [different ways](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangea1notation). One is A1 notation!

```
function onEdit(e) {
var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet(),
    editCols = [2, 3, 4, 10, 11, 12]
if (sheet.getName() !== 'Dashboard' || editCols.indexOf(e.range.columnStart) ==
    -1 || e.range.rowStart < 3 || e.range.rowStart > 6) return;
sheet.getRange("A6").setValue(new Date()); //Specifiy one specific cell to add a current Date obj.
```